# Generate XLS File from Page List in Pega PRPC

Tags: java, xls, pega

I'm working in PRPC 7.x; I need to generate an xls file with two worksheets each of which is basically just information copied from each of two page lists.

We don't have any jars aside from default PRPC, which means we don't have apache poi. We do have access to iText, I am unfamiliar with the library but am informed it may have potential use here.

Is there a way in PRPC to generate simple XLS files with a high degree of control?

Comment: Apache POI jars are shipped already with PRPC 7.x.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 OOTB activities using which we can generate the XLS. 
- ExportToExcel in @baseclass
- ViewExportToExcel in Rule-Obj-HTML.

One of this should help, let me know if you need any more info.

## Rulesware